# vba auto filter greater than / less than 0

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter those that are positive numbers, remove filter, then filter the negative ones, then remove filter again.

I use this code, this doesn't work.

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">0"
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<0"
```

Could you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't remove any filters in your code. By the way, what do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I wanted to filter all the negative values, get their absolute sum and copy it to another workbook. Then remove filters to do the same with the positive numbers.

Comment: You want to copy the data or the sum to another page? If its the sum, you can just use a `SUMIF` statement without all the filtering. Something like `=SUMIF(G:G,">0",G:G)` for your (**+**) values and `=ABS(SUMIF(G:G,"<0",G:G))` for your (**-**) values

Comment: I wanted to use Macro vba for this...

Answer (score 1):

This will:

1. Check to see if a filter is already applied. if not, turn on filter
2. Apply filter 1 (`>0`)
3. Remove filter
4. Apply filter 2 (`<0`)
5. Remove filter

The code, as is, is just applying the filters and then turning them off. This means you will not see anything happen when you run the code. If you step through the code using (`F8`), and remove the `ScreenUpdating = False`, you will see everything happen on your sheet.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Put your sheet name inside the quotes

With ws
  If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .Range("G1").AutoFilter

     'First Critiera
     .Range("G1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">0"
         'Do what you want with your filtered data here
     .AutoFilterMode = False

     'Second Criteria
     .Range("G1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<0"
         'Do what you want with your filtered data here
     .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! that code gives me the error "Autofilter Method of Range class failed"
When I tried debugging it, the error was in the line ".Range("G1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">0"   "

Comment: You need to put this on the sheet that has the data to be filter in VBE. Tested and working on my end

Comment: HI, I was able to filter the data. But when I tried deleting the data and replacing it with another (same format whatsoever, just different values), and the filter vba won't work anymore.

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Your initial question was about filtering data, which this does